# Disable internal and external speakers and allow only earphones to watch video or listen Audio

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, android-video-player

I have some videos of which audios sound should be available only through earphone, not from inbuilt speaker or external speakers.
NOTE: It should not allow External Speakers with 3.5mm jack.
What is the possibility to solve it?
It will be great if anybody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the headset is plugged in:

```
private boolean isHeadphonesPlugged(){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_ALL);
        for(AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : audioDevices){
            if(deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES
                    || deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In a separated thread checks if the headPhones are going to be plugged out using the method above(in that case you have to stop your mediaPlayer and apply your logic)!

For [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo)

Comment: I checked with this but this code allowing external speaker

Comment: i want to play audio only from earphones with 3.5 mm jack  it should not play with external speakers with 3.55 jack

Comment: it worked when i used only TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET. Thanks